# The "Better Comments" extension does not work with rust-analyzer

Tags: vscode-extensions, rust-analyzer

I use several extensions in my Visual Studio Code. Two of them are "Better Comments" and "rust-analyzer". The problem is that only in files with the .rs extension, the "Better Comments" extension does not color the comments. I turned off "rust-analyzer" and suddenly comments were colored normally, so it's definitely "rust-analyzer" fault. I searched various forums and unfortunately I did not find a solution. Could someone try to help?

[image]

[image]

I tried with files like: .js, ts, .cs and it worked